# Weighted average of covariance matrixes

Tags: probability, covariance, covariance-matrix, weighted-mean

My issue is as follows:

In my model there are 4 different states, which each have a calculated probability of happening. I also have calculated covariance matrixes for my variables in each of these states based on historical movement. So I have a covariance matrix for state 1, state 2, state 3, and state 4, plus a probability for each of the states happening.

What I am trying to do is calculate an "expected" covariance matrix based on the historical data of the variables and the calculated probabilities of the 4 different states, basically as a weighted average (in the same way you would do with e.g. stock returns).

So basically the question is, can you calculate a weighted average for variance and covariance? Can I simply calculate a weighted average across the four covariance matrixes based on the probabilities of the states, or is there something I have to take into account when combining them? Or am I even approaching this completely wrong?

Comment: Do the expected values differ between the four states?

Comment: you may be interested in the iterated covariance formula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_covariance (in the Wiki, $Z$ is going to correspond to the "state" from your post).

Comment: @JarleTufto Yeah, they differ very meaningfully between the states

Comment: @JohnMadden Thank you, will take a look at this